# Flickering issue with tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net

VB.net 2010
I have searched for a solution to this problem and tried all of the ones I could find.  The odd thing is that there is no flickering on a windows XP operating system.  Vista ans windows 8 is where the problem occurs.  The Application has a tab control with a image list that gets changed by this code in a timer

```
If Data(3) <> 0 Then
        CLXtpIconBit = True
    Else
        CLXtpIconBit = False
    End If
    If CLXtpIconBit = True Then
        TPclxStat.ImageIndex = 1
        PLC_TLNE_count = PLC_TLNE_count + 1
    Else
        TPclxStat.ImageIndex = 0
    End If
```

If I don't call the above code the flickering goes away.

I Have tried the doublebuffered = true
   backgroundimagelayout to strech
   adding a class but it is for a panel

```
Public Class DoubleBufferedPanel
Inherits Panel
Public Sub New()
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried many other changes in the property's of the Tabcontrol and the Tabpages.

Also there are 16 Basic Label's on the tab pages.  Out of 3 tab pages on one of them 2 of the 16 label's mid way through the text like after 7 characters the rest of the text is flashing very rapidly.

Came up with this for the tab flickering

```
    If Data(2) <> 0 Then
        ND1tpIconBit = True
    Else
        ND1tpIconBit = False
    End If

    If ND1tpIconBit = True And OneShot(2) = False Then
        OneShot(2) = True
        TPnd1Stat.ImageIndex = 1
    End If

    If ND1tpIconBit = False And OneShot(2) = True Then
        OneShot(2) = False
        TPnd1Stat.ImageIndex = 0
    End If
```

m

Comment: Every time the timer touches it, it repaints and updates it with the code you displayed above. That will make it look like it is flashing. Every time you change image index, it will flicker. This isn't a property related issue really.

Comment: Thanks sparkysworld... I was thinking the same thing.  So is there a different way to change the image index without repaint?   I still don't get that in XP it is fine but on newer OS's it occurs.

Comment: I also forgot one of the other problems.  On one of the tabpages out of 16 simple labels 2 of them half of the horizontal text flickers like crazy. This is  even with out the timer or any change by code at all to the Tabcontrol    thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with the "other problems".

Comment: OK I changed my post.

Comment: "So is there a different way to change the image index without repaint?" I think what you're looking for is not a different way to change the index, but to do it on a less regular basis so it doesn't turn into a flip book. I suggest you look at what exact event you want the image to change (say on a button click, or a tab index change) and insert the code there instead.

Comment: On your label issue, when you repaint a form (like a tab) it will repaint/refresh the *whole* form and all attached items, like labels on top of it. It may be other things too. Also look at where the labels are edited in your code, and put a breakpoint. See who often they are changed. Make sure they only are touched at a rate that isn't that fast.

Comment: Great, I thought about that Sparky and came up with this.
    If Data(2) <> 0 Then
            ND1tpIconBit = True
        Else
            ND1tpIconBit = False
        End If

        If ND1tpIconBit = True And OneShot(2) = False Then
            OneShot(2) = True
            TPnd1Stat.ImageIndex = 1
        End If

        If ND1tpIconBit = False And OneShot(2) = True Then
            OneShot(2) = False
            TPnd1Stat.ImageIndex = 0
        End If

Now I just need to figure out how to stop the Labels from flickering on that one tab

Comment: Have you tried using ` SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)` ?

Comment: No I have not tried that.  How or where should I put that line?